# How to snap already digitized polygons in different layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, snapping

As a newbie, I have digitized a lot of polygons without snapping them.

Is there any way that I can add snapping to them aftervards? They are in different layers?

Answer (score 4):

You can run "[Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer)" from [processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html).

You may want to try different tolerances and behaviors.

[image]

Snapping can be done to an existing node or a segment (its closest point to the vertex to move). Available snapping options:

> 0 — Prefer aligning nodes, insert extra vertices where required
>
> Prefer to snap to nodes, even when a segment may be closer than a
> node. New nodes will be inserted to make geometries follow each other
> exactly when inside allowable tolerance.
>
> 1 — Prefer closest point, insert extra vertices where required
>
> Snap to closest point, regardless of it is a node or a segment. New
> nodes will be inserted to make geometries follow each other exactly
> when inside allowable tolerance.
>
> 2 — Prefer aligning nodes, don’t insert new vertices
>
> Prefer to snap to nodes, even when a segment may be closer than a
> node. No new nodes will be inserted.
>
> 3 — Prefer closest point, don’t insert new vertices
>
> Snap to closest point, regardless of it is a node or a segment. No new
> nodes will be inserted.
>
> 4 — Move end points only, prefer aligning nodes
>
> Only snap start/end points of lines (point features will also be
> snapped, polygon features will not be modified), prefer to snap to
> nodes.
>
> 5 — Move end points only, prefer closest point
>
> Only snap start/end points of lines (point features will also be
> snapped, polygon features will not be modified), snap to closest point
>
> 6 — Snap end points to end points only
>
> Only snap the start/end points of lines to other start/end points of
> lines
>
> 7 — Snap to anchor nodes (single layer only)

Answer (score 1):

Snapping options do not work retroactively.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not do this automatically. But you could turn on the editing mode of one layer as well as snapping to the other layer and do this by hand vertex per vertex. It may, however, be faster and easier to do at least one of the layers again with snapping and tracing activated.